# How to Model Constrained Outcome in Multivariate Regression Context

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, constraint, constrained-regression

I have a problem in which the ratio of two different outcomes as a function of time $\frac{Y_{1t}}{Y_{2t}}$ is unknown constant $c$. I would like to estimate regression models of the following type:

$$
Y_{1t} = \beta_{11} \ln{t} +\epsilon_{1t}
$$

and

$$
Y_{2t} = \beta_{21} \ln{t} +\epsilon_{2t}
$$

I am not wedded to an untransformed $\frac{Y_{1t}}{Y_{2t}} = c$ and would be happy to work with, for instance, $\ln{Y_{1t}} - \ln{Y_{2t}} = k$. It has been surprisingly hard to find any resources for what must be a quite common problem in multivariate time series. $Y_{jt}$ can be assumed stationary and I have no particular error structure in mind for this problem. I am interested in both estimation and inference (from a frequentist perspective) if anyone has seen this problem before.

Comment: Just a hunch in what you could do: Use $Y_{1t} =  c \beta_{21}\ln t + c \varepsilon_{1t}$ and use nonlinear regression to estimate $c,\beta_{21}$. Remember to account for the correlation between the observations.

Comment: Thanks, my hunch is that there is an elegant solution using vector autoregression. Fingers crossed.